# Fgets() but on a string instead of a file?

Tags: php, fgets

I can do the following:

```
$fopen = fopen($file_name, 'r');
$data = fgets($fopen, 16384);
fclose($fopen);
```

But is their any way I could emulate the same functionality but on a string (instead of using a file name)?

```
$string = file_get_contents($file_name); /* just for demonstration purposes */
$data = /* do something here...*/
```

Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of function defined for String manipulation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php).
You can choose any of them which fulfills your requirements.

Probably you need `substr()`

Answer (score 4):

[This manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) documents a custom stream wrapper that can be used to give

> read/write access to a named global
>   variable using standard filesystem
>   stream functions such as fread(). The
>   var:// protocol implemented below,
>   given the URL "var://foo" will
>   read/write data to/from
>   $GLOBALS["foo"].

This would allow you to do:

```
$fp = fopen('var://string', 'r');
$data = fgets($fp, 16384);
```

to 'fread() from $string'.

Comment: I personally think this was the correct answer but for my situation this proved to be entirely to slow to use.

Comment: @Typo how did u mesure that this was to slow?

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode("\n", $data);

foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {  
    $parts[$key] = substr($parts[$key], 0, 16384);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like internal pointers too. You can always:

```
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fwrite($fp, $string);
rewind($fp);
```

I also saw a one-liner equivalent that goes like this:

```
$fp = fopen('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($string), 'r');
```

... which is elegant but has the caveat of a redundant encoding step.

Answer (score -1):

Humm... Not sure what you want but have you looked into [`substr()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)?

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = file_get_contents($file_name); /* just for demonstration purposes */
$data = substr($string, 0, 16384);
```

Or maybe do you want ton consume a part of the string for each call to the function?